# Identifying and highlighting invalid geometries using QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry

I'm am trying to clean/edit shapefiles that were created by algorithm in QGIS. My problem is when I try to split some polygons, they have invalid geometry.

Is a way to identify these errors, maybe in a different colour, for me to fix them?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Topology Checker plugin**. With it you can set topological rules and highlight where the problems are. Check the documentation [here](http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_topology_checker.html).

Some error can be corrected by some processing tools. Please check this Faunalia videos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BqJbVh_OqCE

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1ChPvsC4bU