# Selecting strange line-like objects in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I'm having a difficult time trying to select what seems to be a dead polygon.

Does anybody know how do I get rid of those using select and delete operations?

I'm attaching an image to help me explain the issue. If the line-like object pictured was a feature, it's ID should appear selected on the attribute table
of the layer I'm working on. Now, thatś not what happens when I try to select 
this object using the select feature tool or the node tool.

Here's what QGIS tells me when I try `Check Geometry Validity` on the problematic layer. After logging the following text, the tool freezes in 1% and stays there, never completing the validation process. However, it seems that QGIS performs geometry validitation everytime I toogle off editing mode and at that moment no errors are found.

```
An error has occured while executing Python code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/fTools/tools/doValidate.py", line 284, in run
    success = self.check_geometry( self.vlayer )
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/fTools/tools/doValidate.py", line 309, in check_geometry
    geom = QgsGeometry(feat.geometry()) # ger reference to geometry
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QgsGeometry(): too many arguments
  QgsGeometry(QgsGeometry): argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'

Python version:
2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 20:11:37) 
[GCC 4.6.3]


QGIS version:
2.4.0-Chugiak Chugiak, exported

Python path: ['/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing', '/usr/share/qgis/python', u'/home/dvalenteneto/.qgis2/python', u'/home/dvalenteneto/.qgis2/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/fTools/tools', '/home/dvalenteneto/Proyectos/Visualizador Poder Judicial/Shapes Simplificados del Atlas Judicial']
```

[image: GUI moment]

[image: Check validity]

Comment: Possible bad geometry? Have you run a geometry validator/check such as the process at this [blog post](http://faunaliagis.wordpress.com/2013/08/14/bad-bad-polygon-fixing-invalid-geometries-with-quantum-gis/)?

Comment: When you select the object using the _Select feature tool_, can you click the _Delete selected_ button (just to the right of the _Node Tool_ button or is it grayed out?

Comment: @ChrisW check it out the question again. I edited it with some preliminary result after trying a geometry validation. It didn't work for me this time.

Comment: @Joseph the `selection tool` never selects the line-like object, as a result I always get a grayed out `delete selected` button.

Comment: Not being a regular QGIS user, nothing else immediately comes to mind aside from going to the extreme solution - select everything that *is* valid and export it to a new file. I believe there are other cleanup options, including those discussed at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104326/invalid-geometry and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95414/how-to-identify-and-highlight-invalid-geometries which may help. Beyond that, posting the file for people to test may be helpful if that is an option.